# Adding multiple images through Arrays

Tags: java, arrays

Can we add multiple images in Java through arrays?
Like if we want to store each picture in an array 
and then display it through a loop? 
And 
This displays all the picture at a time. I want to display one picture then another one after some time

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    String path = "C:\\Users\\MR\\Downloads\\Body Parts";
    JFrame frame=new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

    File folder = new File(path);
    File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
    DefaultListModel listModel = new DefaultListModel();
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++)
    {
        System.out.println("check path"+listOfFiles[i]);
        String name = listOfFiles[i].toString();


        // load only JPEGs
        if ( name.endsWith("jpg") ) {
            ImageIcon ii = new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(listOfFiles[i]));
            listModel.add(count++, ii);
        }
    }

    JList lsm=new JList(listModel);
    lsm.setVisibleRowCount(1);

    frame.add(new JScrollPane(lsm));

    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: ....yes we can!

Comment: Display it where? A website? A desktop Application? Where's your code?

Comment: I have to make a code for animation. It Isnt ready yet.
I have multiple images and i want to display them one by one.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Internally an array is a sequential chunk of heap memory and you can store anything /of reasonable size/.

Comment: Keep in mind that what you're storing in each array element isn't the image itself, but a reference to it.

Comment: This answer is not useful because it just says "yes, you can store data in an array".

Comment: --jsheeran<< that is true. Good note.